# How to define a replace string function?

Tags: python, string

What is my error in this string function? Cannot figure out what I did wrong.

Return a string like `s`, but with all instances of `orig` replaced with `repl`.

```
Example:
>>> replace('Hellx wxrld', 'x', 'o')
'Hello world'
```

```
def replace(s, orig, repl):
    s.replace(orig, repl)
    return s
```

Comment: Strings are immutable - `s.replace` can't change the value of `s`, it can only create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) says "Return a copy of the string" which means that the `s` variable isn't modified, so you need to modify your code to return the `replace`.

```py
def replace(s, orig, repl):
    return s.replace(orig, repl)
```